# Is it possible to modify stdin for some daily commands?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, ack, iterm2

Here is the feature I wanted.

Every time I want to search something in my project directory.
I use ack to search some keyword for me.

`ack hey`

And sometimes I want to search more than one word. So I type

`ack "hey there"`

I wish the double quote can be auto completed after I type ack and press tab, and the cursor can be focus between the double quotes.

Somebody know how to make it?

I had tried to make a oh-my-zsh plugin for this. But seems I need some guide for help.

```
function _ack_commands() {
    echo -n '"'
}

compdef _ack_commands ack
```

Comment: If it helps, single quotes are easier to type (no shift key): `ack 'hey there'`.

Comment: Haha, it helps a little.

Comment: it would be easier to write a function that took all arguments and passed it quoted to `ack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use

```
zsh -f
ack() { command ack "$*" }
ack hey there
```

or something along these lines?

[...]

Actually I was curious if I could write something along what you described. I have to reckon that my zsh-fu is not enough for it.

To muck with the cursor position, you would normally change the `CURSOR` value (see `man zshzle`). From within zle widgets you would access special values by using `zmodload -i zsh/parameter` (see `man zshmodules`). But the trick is that -as stated in the `zshzle` man page):

> Inside  completion widgets and traps called while ZLE is active, these parameters are available read-only.

So we can't change the value of `CURSOR` from inside a completion widget.

Comment: I add ```ack() { command ack "$@" }``` in my .zshrc file, but seems it does not work.

Comment: I told you you had to check the param expansion :-P I checked it, Use "$*" and it should work.

Comment: great! it's a simple and smart solution!